# How to customize ModelMapper

Tags: java, rest, modelmapper

I want to use ModelMapper to convert entity to DTO and back. Mostly it works, but how do I customize it. It has has so many options that it's hard to figure out where to start. What's best practice?

I'll answer it myself below, but if another answer is better I'll accept it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

First here are some links

- [modelmapper getting started](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/)
- [api doc](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc)
- [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128093810/http://www.talangsoft.org/2015/04/20/domain_mapping_with_modelmapper/)
- [random code examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.modelmapper.ModelMapper)

My impression of mm is that it is very well engineered. The code is solid and a pleasure to read.  However, the documentation is very terse, with very few examples. Also the api is confusing because there seems to be 10 ways to do anything, and no indication of why you’d do it one way or another.

There are two alternatives: [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) is the most popular, and [Orika](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/) gets good reviews for ease of use.

Assuming you still want to use mm, here’s what I’ve learned about it.

The main class, `ModelMapper`, should be a singleton in your app. For me, that meant a @Bean using Spring.  It works out of the box for simple cases. For example, suppose you have two classes:

```
class DogData
{
    private String name;
    private int mass;
}

class DogInfo
{
    private String name;
    private boolean large;
}
```

with appropriate getters/setters.   You can do this:

```
    ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
    DogData dd = new DogData();
    dd.setName("fido");
    dd.setMass(70);
    DogInfo di = mm.map(dd, DogInfo.class);
```

and the "name" will be copied from dd to di.

There are many ways to customize mm, but first you need to understand how it works.

The mm object contains a TypeMap for each ordered pair of types, such as <DogInfo, DogData> and <DogData, DogInfo> would be two TypeMaps.

Each **TypeMap** contains a **PropertyMap** with a list of mappings.  So in the example the mm will automatically create a TypeMap<DogData, DogInfo> that contains a PropertyMap that has a single mapping.

We can write this

```
    TypeMap<DogData, DogInfo> tm = mm.getTypeMap(DogData.class, DogInfo.class);
    List<Mapping> list = tm.getMappings();
    for (Mapping m : list)
    {
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

and it will output

```
PropertyMapping[DogData.name -> DogInfo.name]
```

When you call **mm.map()** this is what it does,

1. see if the **TypeMap** exists yet, if not create the TypeMap for the <S,
   D> source/destination types
2. call the TypeMap **Condition**, if it returns FALSE, do nothing and STOP
3. call the TypeMap **Provider** to construct a new destination object if necessary
4. call the TypeMap **PreConverter** if it has one
5. do one of the following:

   - if the TypeMap has a **custom Converter**, call it
   - or, generate a **PropertyMap** (based on **Configuration flags** plus any **custom mappings** that were added), and use it
     (Note: the TypeMap also has optional custom Pre/PostPropertyConverters that *I think* will run at this point before and after *each mapping*.)
6. call the TypeMap **PostConverter** if it has one

Caveat: This flowchart is [sort of documented](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/how-it-works/) but I had to guess a lot, so it might not be all correct!

You can customize *every single step* of this process. But the two most common are

- step 5a. – write custom TypeMap Converter, or
- step 5b. – write custom Property Mapping.

Here is a sample of a **custom TypeMap Converter**:

```
    Converter<DogData, DogInfo> myConverter = new Converter<DogData, DogInfo>()
    {
        public DogInfo convert(MappingContext<DogData, DogInfo> context)
        {
            DogData s = context.getSource();
            DogInfo d = context.getDestination();
            d.setName(s.getName());
            d.setLarge(s.getMass() > 25);
            return d;
        }
    };

    mm.addConverter(myConverter);
```

**Note** the converter is *one-way*. You have to write another if you want to customize DogInfo to DogData.

Here is a sample of a **custom PropertyMap**:

```
    Converter<Integer, Boolean> convertMassToLarge = new Converter<Integer, Boolean>()
    {
        public Boolean convert(MappingContext<Integer, Boolean> context)
        {
            // If the dog weighs more than 25, then it must be large
            return context.getSource() > 25;
        }
    };

    PropertyMap<DogData, DogInfo> mymap = new PropertyMap<DogData, DogInfo>()
    {
        protected void configure()
        {
            // Note: this is not normal code. It is "EDSL" so don't get confused
            map(source.getName()).setName(null);
            using(convertMassToLarge).map(source.getMass()).setLarge(false);
        }
    };

    mm.addMappings(mymap);
```

The pm.configure function is really funky. It’s not actual code. It is dummy [EDSL code](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/PropertyMap.html) that gets interpreted somehow. For instance the parameter to the setter is not relevant, it is just a placeholder.  You can do lots of stuff in here, such as

- when(condition).map(getter).setter
- when(condition).skip().setter                – safely ignore field.
- using(converter).map(getter).setter          – custom field converter
- with(provider).map(getter).setter           – custom field constructor

**Note** the custom mappings are *added* to the default mappings, so you do *not* need, for example, to specify

```
            map(source.getName()).setName(null);
```

in your custom PropertyMap.configure().

In this example, I had to write a **Converter** to map Integer to Boolean. In most cases this will not be necessary because mm will automatically convert Integer to String, etc.

I'm told you can also create mappings [using Java 8 lambda](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/) expressions. I tried, but I could not figure it out.

**Final Recommendations and Best Practice**

By default mm uses `MatchingStrategies.STANDARD` which is dangerous. It can easily choose the wrong mapping and cause strange, hard to find bugs. And what if next year someone else adds a new column to the database? So don't do it. Make sure you use STRICT mode:

```
    mm.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```

Always write unit tests and ensure that all mappings are validated.

```
    DogInfo di = mm.map(dd, DogInfo.class);
    mm.validate();   // make sure nothing in the destination is accidentally skipped
```

Fix any validation failures with `mm.addMappings()` as shown above.

Put all your mappings in a central place, where the mm singleton is created.

Comment: If I a complex Object for intance: `Person{ private String name, private Address address}, Address{String city, String street}` and I like to map a Dto object `DTO{ private String name, private String addressCity, private String addressStreet}` what should be called the properties of the DTO if I use the modelmapper STRICT mode ? or I need configure two custom PropertyMap?, because in STANDAR mode works, but in STRICT mode, it stops working in the example. Thanks!

Comment: @AlejoDev, in that case you can use standard mode (and understand the risk).  Or you can use strict mode and you can write two TypeMaps.  One typemap for Person to PersonDTO and another for the reverse map.

Comment: @JohnHenckel validate() does not throw an exception for me. I have a model where the property is called foo and in the second model it's called bar. As a result, foo is null. Im also using strict mode. Have you seen that issue before?

Comment: @Marc sorry no, i have not seen that. You should get error for each destination property that is unmatched. Maybe the properties must be public? i don't know.

Comment: @JohnHenckel since you've mentioned using Spring in your post. Did you noticed a substantial increment of the time needed to configure the spring context after using ModelMapper? With version 2.3.2 our spring boot application starts in 1min and with version 2.3.3 it takes 4min to start, which is extremely frustrating. I've noticed that it is because of the .addMapping method. https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/462

Comment: Is there a simple approach to find all typemappings in the code and add them to the modelmapper singleton? I don't want to configure all typemappings in Application.java. E.g. like in C# AutoMapper where you can do 

services.AddAutoMapper(
                typeof(XYZMappingProfile).Assembly);

Comment: The alternative Dozer is deprecating.

Comment: fyi: [blog post](https://www.talangsoft.org/2015/04/20/domain_mapping_with_modelmapper/) link is broken now

Answer (score 12):

I faced a problem while mapping with ModelMapper. Not only properties but also My source and destination type were different. I solved this problem by doing this ->

if the source and destination type are different. For example,

```
@Entity
class Student {
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "laptop_id")
    private Laptop laptop;
}
```

And Dto ->

```
class StudentDto {
    private Long id;
    private LaptopDto laptopDto;
}
```

Here, the source and destination types are different. So, if your MatchingStrategies are STRICT, you won't able to map between these two different types.
Now to solve this, Just simply put this below code in the constructor of your controller class or any class where you want to use ModelMapper->

```
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

public StudentController(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    this.modelMapper.typeMap(Student.class, StudentDto.class).addMapping(Student::getLaptop, StudentDto::setLaptopDto);
}
```

That's it. Now you can use ModelMapper.map(source, destination) easily. It will map automatically

```
modelMapper.map(student, studentDto);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been using it from last 6 months, I'm going to explain some of my thoughts about that:

First of all, it is recommended to use it as an unique instance (singleton, spring bean,...), that's explained in the manual, and I think all agree with that.

`ModelMapper` is a great mapping library and wide flexible. Due to its flexibility, there are many ways to get the same result, and that's why it should be in the manual of best practices of when to use one or other way to do the same thing.

Starting with `ModelMapper` is a little bit difficult, it has a very tight learning curve and sometimes it is not easy to understand the best ways to do something, or how to do some other thing. So, to start it is required to read and understand the manual precisely.

You can configure your mapping as you want using the next settings:

```
Access level
Field matching
Naming convention
Name transformer
Name tokenizer 
Matching strategy
```

The default configuration is simply the best (http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/), but if you want to customise it you are able to do it.

Just one thing related to the Matching Strategy configuration, I think this is the most important configuration and is need to be careful with it. I would use the `Strict` or `Standard` but never the `Loose`, why?

- Due Loose is the most flexible and intelligent mapper it could be map some properties you can not expect. So, definitively, be careful with it. I think is better to create your own PropertyMap and use Converters if it is needed instead of configuring it as Loose.

Otherwise, it is important to `validate` all property matches, you verify all it works, and with ModelMapper it's more need due with intelligent mapping it is done via reflection so you will not have the compiler help, it will continue compiling but the mapping will fail without realising it. That's one of the things I least like, but it needs to avoid boilerplate and manual mapping.

Finally, if you are sure to use ModelMapper in your project you should use it using the way it proposes, don't mix it with manual mappings (for example), just use ModelMapper, if you don't know how to do something be sure is possible (investigate,...). Sometimes is hard to do it with model mapper (I also don't like it) as doing by hand but is the price you should pay to avoid boilerplate mappings in other POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can make a customize Conversion Class and can then autowire it where you would like to convert the object to dto and vice versa.

```
@Component
public class ConversionUtil {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    public <T,D> D mapItem(T item,Class<D> cl){
        return modelMapper().map(item,cl);
    }
    public <T,D> List<D> map(List<T> list, Class<D> cl){
        return list.stream()
                .map(item -> modelMapper().map(item, cl))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EntityDtoConversionUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public Object convert(Object object,Class<?> type) {

        Object MapperObject=modelMapper.map(object, type);

        return MapperObject;

    }


}
```