# Is there a way to change default mapping?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I want to map a `SourceClass` type to a `DestinationClass` type.

```java
public class SourceClass {

    private Integer id;

    private String number;

    private String username;

    private String email;

}
```

```java
public class DestinationClass {

    private Integer id;

    private Map<String, Object> number;

    private Map<String, Object> username;

    private Map<String, Object> email;

}
```

Currently I using a custom `Converter` to do the mapping, to convert `String` to `Map<String, Object>`.

```java
// this function will new and set a map object
public Map<String, Object> setData(String title, Object value {
    Map<String, Object> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    result.put("title", title);
    result.put("value", value);

    return result;
}

// this function will return my custom converter
public Converter<String, Map<String, Object>> myConverter(String title) {
    // LocalI18nUtils.getString(String key) input key and get the translation
    return ctx -> setData(LocalI18nUtils.getString(title), ctx.getSource());
}
```

And use `modelMapper.addMappings()`

```java
PropertyMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass> mappings = new PropertyMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() { 
using(myConverter("Number"))).map(source.getNumber()).setNumber(null);
using(myConverter("Username"))).map(source.getUsername()).setUsername(null);
using(myConverter("Email"))).map(source.getEmail()).setEmail(null);
    }
}

// source is SourceClass type object
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addMappings(mappings);
modelMapper.map(source, DestinationClass.class);
```

So, the source object and destination object should be:

```
// source
{
    "id": 1,
    "number": "mem_0001",
    "username": "member0001",
    "email": "member001@mail.com"
}
```

```
// destination
{
    "id": 1,
    "number": {
        "title": "Number",
        "value": "mem_0001"
    },
    "username": {
        "title": "Username",
        "value": "member0001"
    },
    "email": {
        "title": "Email",
        "value": "member001@mail.com"
    }
}
```

I have read this question before => [How to customize ModelMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534172/how-to-customize-modelmapper/44534173)

The solution note the `ModelMapper` custom mappings are added to the default mappings, so you do not need, for example, to specify `id`:

```java
//  you don't need to write this statement.
map(source.getId()).setId(null);
```

So I am thinking about, is there anyway to change (or override) the default mappings, so that I can write less code.

Maybe it looks like:

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
// ...
// something will change default mappings to myConverter 
// ...
modelMapper.map(source, DestinationClass.class);
```

Thank you for all Helps and Answers.

Comment: Off topic but why do you want to go from String to Object for you class variables and lose that type information?

Comment: Because some input is "123.456" (String) and other is 123.456 (Number), I do not know the input type. So I declare the output class variable is Object. But in this question, you can change Object to String.