# GetTypeMap returns Null for LinkedHashMap to DTO mapping

Tags: java, modelmapper

Currently using model Mapper to map some fields from a LinkedHashMap to a DTO. After going through the answer [Customize modelMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534172/how-to-customize-modelmapper), learnt that model Mapper creates a TypeMap for every ordered pair of types being mapped using the map() method of modelMapper.

### Working scenario

Consider the following class:

```
class A { 
    
    private String name;
    
    // Getters and setters here
 }
```

In another class, the following was tried:

```
Class C {
    
     public void mapEntities() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashmap<>();
        map.put("name", "b");
        A a = new A();
        modelMapper.map(map, a);
        
        System.out.println(a.getName);
        TypeMap<A, B> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(LinkedHashMap.class, A.class)
        typeMap.getMappings().forEach(System.out::println);
     }
 }
```

### Output

> b
>
> PropertyMapping[name -> A.name]

This seems to confirm that there is a typeMap created for the pair (LinkedHashMap.class,A.class) and it contains a single propertyMap as expected. And also that the mapping was done as well.

### Problem Scenario

In this scenario, the class A contains an extra field as shown below:

```
Class A {
 
  private String name;
  private String details;
  
  // Getters and setters here
}
```

When the same was tried with this added field in class A:

```
 Class C {

    public void mapEntities() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashmap<>();
        map.put("name", "b");
        A a = new A();
        modelMapper.map(map, a);

        
        System.out.println(a.getName);
        TypeMap<A, B> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(LinkedHashMap.class, A.class)
        typeMap.getMappings().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

### Output

However, this throws a **null pointer exception** as typeMap is being returned as null. *So, why is the typeMap for this pair (LinkedHashMap, A) being returned as null?*

**FurtherMore, when examining the object a, the mapping has worked in that, a.getName() returns b.**

---

*Very new to using modelMapper, so is something being missed here or the  understanding about typeMap being created for every pair of objects used in the model.map() method is wrong?*