# How to use modelMapper to convert diffrent object type (Not equal classes)

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I want to use modelmapper on my project. I know how can I use modelmapper on basic level.

There is my Entity classes:

```
public class User {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private AccountType accountType;
}

public class AccountType {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

And there is my response class:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private boolean accountType;
}
```

**So what I want?**

```
response: {
    "userId": "12345",
    "name": "Gokhan",
    "accountType": false
}
```

I want to convert this response to following:

```
User: {
    "userId": "12345",
    "name": "Gokhan",
    "AccountType " : {
        "id" : "2"
        "name" : "",
    }
}
```

I mean,

```
if(response.accountType) 
    user.getAccountTpe.setId(1);
 else user.getAccountTpe.setId(2);
```

*NOTE: I wrote "User" in JSON format in the end. But I need it in JAVA.*

Answer (score 0):

You need custom converter:

```
public class UserConverter implements Converter<UserModel, User> {

    @Override
    public User convert(MappingContext<UserModel, User> context) {
        UserModel source = context.getSource();
        User destination = context.getDestination() == null ? new User() : context.getDestination();
        destination.setUserId(source.getUserId());
        destination.setName(source.getName());
        int accountTypeId = source.isAccountType() ? 1 : 2;
        AccountType accountType = new AccountType();
        accountType.setId(accountTypeId);
        accountType.setName("");
        destination.setAccountType(accountType);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Get source object from context, get destination object, if initialized(sometimes it's not). You could use some other instance of mm to avoid setting fields with matching names manually(like `userId`, for example).

Then you need to register converter with your mm instance - `mapper.addConverter(new UserConverter());`.

Main to test stuff:

```
public class ConfMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        //register your custom converter
        mapper.addConverter(new UserConverter());
        //test data
        UserModel model = new UserModel();
        model.setUserId("12345");
        model.setName("Gokhan");
        model.setAccountType(true);

        User user = mapper.map(model, User.class);
        System.out.println("user id - " + user.getUserId());
        System.out.println("user name - " + user.getName());
        System.out.println("account id - " + user.getAccountType().getId());
    }
}
```

I would sugges to read some additional resources on model mapper - like this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper), and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534172/how-to-customize-modelmapper).